# ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram.utils'

Tags: python, aiogram, pycharm

```
from aiogram import executor
```

Пытаюсь создать бота в пайтон используя  библиотеку aiogram, но всегда pycharm подчёркивает executor, как ошибку. Удалял и качал заново Пайтон, aiogram, не помогло, искал папку, где лежит aiogram, там есть большинство других функций, но даже когда я дописываю туда execute, Pycharm его не видит, не знаю что делать.
P.S. Все советы из такого же запроса 2 сентября этого года я выполнял, не помогло.

Comment: Поменяйте версии aiogram и python на более ранние. Возможно, вы используете неустойчивые версии.

Answer (score 0):

В *aiogram* версии `3.x` обработчик событий `executor` просто убрали.

Для того, чтобы заново его использовать, переустановите *aiogram* на версию `2.x`, для этого есть команда:

```
$ pip install --force-reinstall -v "aiogram==2.23.1"
```